# Chromedriver got ad error TypeError: environment can only contain strings

Tags: python, django, selenium, celery

I'm using Selenium to open a Chrome Web Page with a user-agent,
whitout Celery all is ok but when I call a def with Celery i got an error:

```
app = Celery()
@app.task(bind=True)
def test(self, post_id):
    lui = Author.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    print lui.pk
    opts = Options()
    opts.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
    dri = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=opts)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pathto\test.py", line 129, in test
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 658, in __init__
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 627, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 1028, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Any suggest?

Comment: normally running chrome in console you would have to use `" "` because there are spaces - `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 ..."`

Comment: try whitout user agent  `driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe)` same result... why?